# Passing slot to grandchild though dynamic component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a wrapper component(**Wrapper.vue**).

```
<component v-for="c of comps" :key="c.componentName" :is="c.componentName">
      <slot :name="c.componentName">
      </slot>
</component>

const comps = 
      [
        {
          componentName: "Child1",
        },
        {
          componentName: "Child2",
        }
      ];
```

**Child1.vue** is something like below

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <slot name="top">Child1 slot top text</slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Child2.vue** is something like below

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <slot name="top">Child2 slot top text</slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want to use the wrapper like below in **App.vue**

```
<Wrapper>
      <template slot="slot1">
        <template slot="top">Inner Content1</template>
      </template>
      <template slot="slot2">
        <template slot="top">Inner Content2</template>
      </template>
</Wrapper>
```

CodeSandbox Link:- https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-burnell-ir8un

It is showing default text from Child1 and Child2 not from App.vue
What should be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed some code and this is the result. The changes I made:

- you had nested the `<template>` tag inside App.vue.
- the wrapper itself needed to have a template for slot named 'top' and inside this template I added a slot with the same name of the component

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-smoke-uzgn7?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: can you please check the sandbox again? i think edit access was revoked somehow.
If i remove c.componentName then all the passed template would be passed for each of components, which would result in repeated output. I want to show only the necessary top slot of each child.

Comment: see my updated answer, I changed the code so it works like expected.

Comment: There could be multiple slots like top, right, left, bottom in Child components. And also i wanted to keep wrapper independent(clean) of the slots available in Child components.

Comment: I think my solution answers the original question.